# Excel Javascript API set note to cell

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins, javascript-api-for-office

Is there a method to set a `note` to a specific `cell` ?

For example, I would like to add something like this:
sheet.getCell(1, 1).note = "My Note";

Comment: I've added the office-js tag to your question to get attention from the Microsoft Office JavaScript kiddies. But I think the answer currently is that comments cannot be accessed through Office-js. Yet.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully they'll add new features within the new release...

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have the Commenting (notes as you put it) feature exposed via our APIs.

Please go and log a feature request on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for us to consider this for future API releases.

-Philip, Developer on the Office Extensibility team